# How to set the value for corresponding value in jquery data table

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, datatables

I create the mvc format data table. But when loading the scriopt its does not match the table data and does not bind in my table row. My code is given below.

```
$.ajax({ 
    // my passing value
    success: function (data) { // i get the data properly 
        $('#Table').dataTable().fnClearTable();
        $.each(data, function (k, v) {
            var ID= v.ID;
            var name= v.name;
            var batch= v.batch;

            $('#Table').dataTable().fnAddData([
                ID,
                name,
                batch
            ]);
        });
    }
});
```

my table:

```
<table id="Table" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>EMP_ID</th>
            <th>EMP_name</th>
            <th>EMP_batch</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

DataTables: http://www.datatables.net/

Comment: are you sure that `$.each(data, function (k, v) {` really iterate over something  ? add console.log / alert to confirm it...

Answer (score 0):

The key to you problem is the response of your AJAX request.  Make sure that it's a proper JSON object composed of an array of objects.  Like this:

```
[
    {
        "ID": 123,
        "name": "slim shady",
        "batch": "smack my batch up"
    },
    {
        "ID": 321,
        "name": "eddie vedder",
        "batch": "yellow ledbetter"
    }
]
```

Your JavaScript works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/upSvJ/

Comment: Thank you. But my content ready from my contoller how it binding?